# only basic searches are working

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm playing with curl querying elasticsearch db through my mac console. But I have troubles to execute more complex searches. So far I can query for match_all like this:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/products/fashion/_search?pretty' -d'
{
   "query" : { "match_all" : {} }
}'
```

And I receive the following data:

```
{
    "took" : 7,
    "timed_out" : false,
    "_shards" : {
        "total" : 5,
        "successful" : 5,
        "failed" : 0
    },
    "hits" : {
        "total" : 915503,
        "max_score" : 1.0,
        "hits" : [
        {
            "_index" : "products",
            "_type" : "fashion",
            "_id" : "57d49ee494efcfdfe0f3abfe",
            "_score" : 1.0,
            "_source" : {
            "doc" : {
                "id" : "57d49ee494efcfdfe0f3abfe",
                "name" : "Shorts",
                "price" : {
                    "value" : 35
                }
            }
        }
    },
    ...........
}
```

I don't have problems to request a mapping like this:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/products/_mapping/fashion?pretty'
```

And the result for price is:

```
.......
"price" : {
    "properties" : {
        "currency" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                }
            }
        },
        "value" : {
            "type" : "long"
        }
    }
},
....
```

But all my attempts to query with filter on "price.value" did not hit.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/products/fashion/_search?pretty' -d'
{
    "query" : {
        "constant_score" : { 
            "filter" : {
                "term" : { 
                    "price.value" : 35
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
{
    "took" : 26,
    "timed_out" : false,
    "_shards" : {
        "total" : 5,
        "successful" : 5,
        "failed" : 0
    },
    "hits" : {
        "total" : 0,
        "max_score" : null,
        "hits" : [ ]
    }
}
```

[This query I took from elasticsearch guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html)

I ran out of ideas and examples how to write this query to return what I obviously have in database. As you might noticed I have at least one document with price.value = 35

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your `price` field is within another field named `doc`, so you need to query `doc.price.value` like this:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/products/fashion/_search?pretty' -d'
{
    "query" : {
        "constant_score" : { 
            "filter" : {
                "term" : { 
                    "doc.price.value" : 35
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: Thank you! Hmm, now I see everything even where this doc came.